# Firebase custom claims doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-admin-sdk

I have an issue with my project - Node.js and Firebase.

I want to add an admin role so I use custom claims according to the docs.
I have 3 functions in the cloud functions:

```
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(context.auth.uid, {
    admin: true
  }).then(() =>'Success!')
    .catch(err => err)
})


exports.getUserRecord = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().getUser(context.auth.uid)
    .then(userRecord => userRecord.customClaims)
    .catch(err => err)
})


exports.deleteAdmin = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(context.auth.uid, null)
    .then(() => 'Deleted admin!')
    .catch(err => err)
})
```

I call the functions directly in the client (http callable) and addAdminRole returns 'Success!' and seems to work. getUserRecord seems to work as well and returns {admin: true} as my custom claims.

Now for the problem. I defined a function to get the user claims in the client side like mentioned in the docs:

```
getRecords() {
      firebaseInstance.auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
      .then(idTokenResult => {console.log("ADMIN:", idTokenResult)})
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

(firebaseInstance is imported and works fine in the whole project)

I don't understand why but the code in the client side returns an object with the claims property but this property doesn't have the admin claim I added in the cloud functions.

if I try to access `idTokenResult.claims.admin` like in the docs it logs me UNDEFINED.

Link to the docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#node.js

Could you clarify to me what's wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claims of a user are stored in their ID token, which is auto-refreshed by the SDK every hour.

Setting a custom claim to a user's profile from the Admin SDK does not force an auto-refresh of the ID token of the clients, so it may take up to an hour before the claim shows up in the clients. The documentation hints at this with:

> **Once the latest claims have propagated to a user's ID token**, you can get them by retrieving the ID token: ...

This documentation could be more explicit though, so I'd recommend leaving feedback with the button at the bottom of that page.

To ensure a claim propagates to a client sooner, you should force the client to refresh its ID token (for example, by passing `true` to `getIdTokenResult()`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, and I left feedback about the partial explenation.